# Custom Core Data mapping: Inserting a new entity in between an existing relationship

Tags: core-data, core-data-migration

An example of my data model **version 1** looks like this:
[image]

*The cake is eaten by some guests.*

In data model **version 2** not every guest will eat the same amount of pieces. I want to assign each guest an individual number of pieces:
[image]

(`numberOfPieces` could be set to a default of 1 pieces.)

How can that be accomplished? I've implemented a custom mapping model and set a custom policy for the mapping `CakeToCake`. However, I'm unsure what to do. Does my policy have to implement `createRelationshipsForDestinationInstance:entityMapping:manager:error:` where I would manually create the `PieceOfCake` object?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Migrating a many-to-many relationship to a join table in Core Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174773/migrating-a-many-to-many-relationship-to-a-join-table-in-core-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I did the right thing and finally created `PieceOfCake` in `createRelationshipsForDestinationInstance:entityMapping:manager:error:`. It works well.